# Block an IP address from accessing my Flask app on Heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, flask, ip, gunicorn

I've got an IP address that I need to block from my website. Running a Flask app on Heroku, and I'm seeing 50 requests per second on my server, and that definitely shouldn't be happening.

I'm familiar with using htaccess on an Apache server, is there anything similar here (Gunicorn server)?

Comment: how about using `remote_addr` with `if` cond ?

Answer (score 18):

Use the flask before_request decorator.  This will get called before each request so you can check a list of banned ip addresses.  Any banned address will be aborted with 403, forbidden.

```
from flask import request, abort, current_app as app

ip_ban_list = ['127.0.0.1']

@app.before_request
def block_method()
    ip = request.environ.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    if ip in ip_ban_list:
        abort(403)
```

Comment: There is a python flask package I've written to ban ip addresses using this technique.  https://github.com/Martlark/flask-ipban

Comment: Thank you @Martlark, I'll try your flask-ipban package!

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [`pre_request`](http://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html#pre-request) server hook from `Gunicorn`:

```
def pre_request(worker, req):
    if req.remote_addr != 'ip to be blocked':
        pass
```

Comment: but what do you do when 'else'?