# Flask: How to get the Client IP Address of the Request?

Tags: python, flask, proxy, request, ip-address

**Problem:**

Hi all - I am basically trying to whitelist certain ip-addresses so that only users using a specific set of networks can access my Flask Microservice's REST endpoints.

**Code Example:**

I have a decorator like this:

```
def check_ip(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        headers_list = request.headers.getlist("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR")
        ip = headers_list[0] if headers_list else request.environ.get('HTTP_X_REAL_IP', request.remote_addr)
        current_app.logger.info(
            {'client_ip_address': request.json['ip']
             }
        )
        if ip:
            if ip in allowed_ip_addresses:
                return f(*args, **kwargs)

        return {'message': 'Forbidden to Access'}, 403

    return decorated
```

**Error:**

The issue I'm facing is that the ip address detected is always 127.0.0.1 (localhost). I can't seem to get the correct IP address of the request. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Desired Solution:**

I would like to be able to acquire the correct ip address of the request sent to the API

**Requirements:**

I'm using Flask and when deployed to production, it's running on Gunicorn

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Block an IP address from accessing my Flask app on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24222220/block-an-ip-address-from-accessing-my-flask-app-on-heroku)